# Getting error while trying to return stored value with notification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am getting this error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null
>   given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\trstbillingapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 35 and defined

while trying to store data with this method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
        ]);
        return $user->notify(new UserRegister($data));
    }
```

If I store the data without notification, it works:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
        ]);
        return $user;
    }
```

Please suggest me another way to pass the notification. I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Can you post your UserRegister class?

Comment: Actually there is nothing much in user register class. Just public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    } and public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'userRegister' => date('Y-m-d')
        ];
    }

Comment: My UserRegister class is working as I can see from database. All data is saved even if I am getting the error. I think trying to pass the notification is creating issue with authentication.

Comment: @Ahsan Please follow this link(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications) its help for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
        ]);
        $user->notify(new UserRegister($data));
        return $user;
    }
```